# Datagrid item rendering

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I was trying to render a html text of some where around 10 strings concatenated together with with in a Datagrigd column . I am able to render it but not to the size of the cell . Im trying to embed this in a HBox and then place it in the cell . But Iam not able to resize to the cell as i see that the HBox is getting shrunk even though there is enough space with in the cell . Can somebody help me out in fitting this  HBox to the size of the Datagrid cell .

I tried using UpdateDisplayList() but its getting into infinite loop and the screen is getting freeze . Please find the code below .

Below is the class iam making a call to the renderer .can somebody please help me out.

package components.myReports
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.containers.HBox;
    import mx.containers.VBox;
    import mx.controls.DataGrid;
    import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
    import mx.core.ClassFactory;
    import renderers.HtmlTextRenderer;

```
public class MyReportsComponent extends VBox
{
    [Bindable]
```

//      public var metersList:ArrayCollection = model.Lookups.getInstance().metersList;

```
    private var _reportsList:ArrayCollection;

    private var myReports:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:"" },
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""},
            {name:"Christina Coenraets",description:"myReports1", dateRefreshed:"05-18-2009", dateCreated:"05-18-2009" , scheduledTime: "05-18-2009",operations:""}

        ]);



    public function MyReportsComponent()
    {
        //TODO: implement function
        super();            

    }

    public function set reportsList(arr:ArrayCollection):void{

        _reportsList = arr

    }




  override protected function createChildren():void  {

      var dataGrid:DataGrid ;
      var dataGridColumn:DataGridColumn;
      var mainContainer:HBox;
      this.removeAllChildren();

      mainContainer = new HBox();
      mainContainer.width = this.parent.width;
      mainContainer.minHeight = 1000;
      mainContainer.horizontalScrollPolicy = "off";
      mainContainer.verticalScrollPolicy = "of";
      mainContainer.percentHeight = 100;
      mainContainer.percentWidth = 75;

      dataGrid =  new DataGrid();

      var row:Array=new Array("name","description","dateRefreshed","dateCreated","scheduledTime","operations");             
      var colName:String; 
      var gridcolumns:Array=new Array(); 
      for(var i:int=0;i<row.length;i++) 
           { 

             dataGridColumn=new DataGridColumn(); 
             dataGridColumn.dataField=row[i].toString(); 
             trace(row[i].toString());
             if(row[i].toString()== "operations")
                {                     
                 dataGridColumn.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(HtmlTextRenderer);                          
                 dataGridColumn.width = 200;
                }else { 
                 dataGridColumn.width = 70;
                }
             dataGridColumn.resizable=true;  

             gridcolumns.push(dataGridColumn); 
        } 

      dataGrid.columns = gridcolumns;         
      dataGrid.width = 700;
      dataGrid.height= 400;
      dataGrid.dataProvider = myReports;
      mainContainer.addChild(dataGrid);
      this.addChild(mainContainer);
      this.validateNow(); 

   }

}
```

}

Renderer-----

package renderers
{
    import mx.containers.HBox;
    import mx.controls.TextArea;

```
public class HtmlTextRenderer extends HBox
{
    private var text:Array=new Array("Edit","Delete","Run","EMail","RetrieveFile","Public","Private","SharedReport","ScheduledReport");
    private var html:String =  null;
    public var operations:TextArea; 

    public function HtmlTextRenderer()
    {
        //TODO: implement function
        super();
    }
    override protected function createChildren():void 
    {
        super.createChildren();         

        for(var i:int = 0 ;i < text.length ;i++)
        {                   
          html+=targetHTML(text[i].toString());

        }   

        operations = new TextArea();
        operations.htmlText =  html; 
        this.percentWidth = 100;
        this.percentHeight = 100;
        this.addChild(operations);         
    }

    private function targetHTML(name:String):String
    {           
        return "<a href='event:" + name +  "'>" + name + "</a>";
    }

    /* override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void{

        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);


    } */


    private function updateSize()
    {
        var w:int = this.measuredWidth +100;
        trace("The width of the Text is "+this.measuredWidth);
        this.width = w;
        this.parent.width = w;

    }  


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just having the item renderer simply be a textArea?